# Bootstrap card scaling

Tags: html, css, object, layout

I am a total novice and trying to create a bootstrap card in which the bottom fits tightly (heightwise) around its contents (incidentally it is a form) and assigns the rest of the height to the image.

The image is then scaled such as to fit the available height and the width is determined such as to keep the aspect ratio and is centered horizontally.

The width and the height of the card should then be determined by whatever layout it is placed in.

Can this even be done in HTML/CSS? Or do I need to go the Javascript path?

I have tried whatever I could think of and could find, nothing works well.

In case it matters, the image is actually an `<object>` with and embedded svg.

Also, I do not require the use of bootstrap. I am just using it for the styling and hoped it would simplify the task.

I hope [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8djcau2/2/) shows the idea. One image is portrait, one is landscape. The portrait image dictates the common height of the cards. The landscape image should fill the width but keep the aspect-ratio.

This is the closest I could get. But the image on the right (the portrait image) should not fill the width.

Comment: OP, please include the code you have already tried and what is not working. Also, add visual cues or snippets to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: It is very hard to make it so concrete, since I have tried many things and did not keep a record of all the attempts.

As visual cues you mean drawings?

Comment: By visual cues, I mean what the UI looks like now VS. what is expected.

Comment: I am trying to make something publishable in jsfiddle and will place the link here